# Objective C: Replace double backslash with a single backslash

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I'm trying to replace a string that holds double backslash to a string with only single backslash, for example:

```
\\This\\Is\\Not\\Working
```

To:

```
\This\Is\Not\Working
```

Using:

```
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\" withString@"\\"];
```

But for some reason, The string remains the same (with the double backslash) every single time. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: And why was this downvoted? :0

Comment: your String is like NSString *Str = @"\\\\This\\\\Is\\\\Not\\\\Working"; ?

Comment: probably because it is not a real error, but a total misinterpretation of the _single_ slash character, which is always represented by _double_ slashes on the debug console when your print the value, or in a string when you want to insert a _single_ slash, you always need to type _double_ slashes to __escape__ the slash character special scope.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I misinterpreted the console log output. the string was fine, the debugger just showed the single slash as a doubled one. (For escaping purposes i'd imagine).

Answer (score 0):

The below lines of code is fine:

```
NSString *str=@"\\This\\Is\\Not\\Working";

str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\" withString@"\\"];
```

Just check value by `NSLog` or by printing, because in debug console slash is represented as double slash.

Check image for more clear understanding:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *Str = @"\\This\\Is\\Not\\Working";
NSLog(@"%@",Str);// print:-\This\Is\Not\Working
Str = [Str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\" withString:@"\\"];// in this no replace occurres
NSLog(@"%@",Str); // print:-\This\Is\Not\Working

NSString *Str1 = @"\\\\This\\\\Is\\\\Not\\\\Working";
NSLog(@"%@",Str1);// print:-\\This\\Is\\Not\\Working
Str1 = [Str1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\" withString:@"\\"];
NSLog(@"%@",Str1);// print:-\This\Is\Not\Working
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString *str = @"\\This\\Is\\Not\\Working";
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"\\\\"];
NSLog(@"%@", [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\" withString:@"\\"]);
```

- 1st Line is your user input.
- 2nd Line converts the double back-slashed user input string into four back-slashed string
- 3rd line simply replaces four back slashes with two back slashes which results in printing single back slash